# Smarty foreach not working

Tags: php, html, smarty

I'm making some experiments with Smarty, but i'm having troubles with a foreach loop, it doesn't work and i can't understand why. Here's my code:

Default.tpl

```
    <select name="user">
    {html_options values=$id output=$names selected="5"}
</select>

<table>
{foreach $names as $name}
{strip}
   <tr bgcolor="{cycle values='#eeeeee,#dddddd'}">
      <td>{$name}</td>
   </tr>
{/strip}
{/foreach}
</table>

<table>
{foreach $users as $user}
{strip}
   <tr bgcolor="{cycle values='#aaaaaa,#bbbbbb'}">
      <td>{$user.name}</td>
      <td>{$user.phone}</td>
   </tr>
{/strip}
{/foreach}
</table>
```

and default.php

```
<?php

include('Smarty.class.php');

//create object
$smarty = new Smarty;

$smarty->template_dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\templates';
$smarty->config_dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\config';
$smarty->cache_dir = 'C:\xampp\php\smarty\cache';
$smarty->compile_dir = 'C:\xampp\php\smarty\templates_c';

$smarty->assign('names', array('Bob', 'Jimmy', 'Freddy', 'Walter', 'Jerry'));

$smarty->assign('users', array(
                        array('name' => 'bob', 'phone' => '555-3425'),
                        array('name' => 'jim', 'phone' => '555-4364'),
                        array('name' => 'joe', 'phone' => '555-3422'),
                        array('name' => 'jerry', 'phone' => '555-4973'),
                        array('name' => 'fred', 'phone' => '555-3235')
));

//display information
$smarty->display('default.tpl');
?>
```

When testing i get the following error:

Fatal error: Smarty error: [in default.tpl line 16]: syntax error: invalid attribute name: '$names' (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 1550) in C:\xampp\php\Smarty\libs\Smarty.class.php on line 1094.

and the same happens to $users. Since i know that the values are passing, because the  is working, i can't understand what's happening.

Thnx in advance.

Edit: i took this example from the smarty website.

Comment: You are using syntax introduced by Smarty3, but are actually running Smarty2. Either upgrade to Smarty3 (3.1.12 is current), or change your foreach to `{foreach from=$users item=user}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the example on the smarty website is not working. This is what i had to do to get it working:

```
    <table>
    {foreach from=$names item=name}
    {strip}
       <tr bgcolor="{cycle values='#eeeeee,#dddddd'}">
          <td>{$name}</td>
       </tr>
    {/strip}
    {/foreach}
</table>

<table>
    {foreach from=$users item=user}
    {strip}
       <tr bgcolor="{cycle values='#aaaaaa,#bbbbbb'}">
          <td>{$user.name}</td>
          <td>{$user.phone}</td>
       </tr>
    {/strip}
    {/foreach}
</table>
```

Comment: may be because you were using some other version of smarty???? than the one the tutorial was written on. The smarty 3 had many many changes.

Comment: I'm using Smarty 2.6.27, i didn't want to download smarty 3 because i will be dealing with 2.6 on work.

Answer (score 1):

```
{foreach name=$names}
.
.
.
.
<td> {$name} </td>
```

This is how it works. I have never tried the way you have used foreach in smarty.

Comment: It told me it was missing the "from" attribute. I added the 'from' and 'item' and now it is running. The information on their website is not correct.